# Import firebase/app used to work now I got error (firestore is not a function)?

Tags: firebase, import, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React and Redux.
I imported firebase using import shown below:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

Everything was working then I committed changes and pushed them to GitHub. My colleague pulled the code and told me to test it and it was not working. I tried to run the code but not working.
I changed the import to:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

the code is working now.
If anyone has an idea what is the reason for this error can you please help me to understand this issue.

Comment: When I use `import * as firebase from 'firebase/firebase'` I receive this warning on the console of the browser **It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-<PACKAGE>.js**

Answer (score 2):

I deleted `package-lock.json` file

Then run `npm install`

I received this warning

```
npm WARN @firebase/firestore@1.0.6 requires a peer of @firebase/app@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/firestore@1.0.6 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/auth@0.9.4 requires a peer of @firebase/app@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/functions@0.4.1 requires a peer of @firebase/app@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/functions@0.4.1 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/messaging@0.3.13 requires a peer of @firebase/app@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/messaging@0.3.13 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/storage@0.2.10 requires a peer of @firebase/app@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/storage@0.2.10 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/auth-types@0.5.3 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/auth-types@0.5.3 requires a peer of @firebase/util@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/firestore-types@1.0.3 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/messaging-types@0.2.6 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/storage-types@0.2.6 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/storage-types@0.2.6 requires a peer of @firebase/util@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I re-installed firebase

```
npm install --save firebase
```

and problem solved. No warnings or errors and it is back to work as before.