# Firebase: 'firebase' not found in 'firebase/app'

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am stuck with a project. I have imported Firebase successfully an hour ago using the code below; the app worked as it should.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

import "firebase/storage";

import "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
  measurementId: "XXX",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();

export { projectStorage, projectFirestore };
```

But now it crashes and says:

> 16:0-22 "export 'initializeApp' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app'
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

I have also tried to stop and restart the program and change the first line by the line below (unsuccessfully):

`import firebase from "firebase/app";`

Can someone help me?

Thanks!
Alison

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import firebase/app used to work now I got error (firestore is not a function)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136252/import-firebase-app-used-to-work-now-i-got-error-firestore-is-not-a-function)

Comment: The docs aren't up to date for the newer versions.  Try this: `import firebase from 'firebase/firebase';`

Comment: Thank you! Actually I've found out that the page was constantly reloading and then Firebase/React crashed. But once this bug was resolved, another one popped up again. Is there an issue when integrating Firebase to React?

Comment: "But once this bug was resolved, another one popped up again. "  Sounds like a normal coding experience to me. :) Firebase plays nicely with React.  Feel free to ask a new question!